# Настройка QTimeEdit

Tags: c++, qt, дата

Нужно настроить *QTimeEdit* следующим образом:

1. Чтобы после достижения 59 секунд (или минут) стрелки не деактивировались, а значение перескакивало на 00 и увеличивались минуты (или часы, соответственно).
2. Чтобы секунды считались через 5.

Проблема в следующем: в документации по поводу подобных возможностей ничего не написано. По поводу первого есть функция `virtual void setAutoAdvance ( bool advance )`, которая вроде подходит, но она виртуальная и при попытке её вызвать компилятор ругается. По поводу второго в документации вообще ничего нет.
Изображение *QTimeEdit*, чтобы было понятно, о чём речь:
[image: Скрин QTimeEdit]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с этим быть?

Comment: Если кратко, то наследовать spinBox и переопределять `stepBy()`... из коробки таких возможностей нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого надо наследовать `QTimeEdit` и переопределить метод `stepBy`.
С шагом в 5 секунд ничего сложного, но дальше возникают проблемы при
приближении к границам. Поэтому в методе есть несколько интересных мест.

Наследуемся от `QTimeEdit`, но границы задаем как `setDateTimeRange`, иначе мы столкнемся с проблемами проверки границ нашего диапазона.

```
class MyTimeEdit : public QTimeEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTimeEdit::MyTimeEdit(QWidget *parent) :
        QTimeEdit(parent)
    {
        // Формат вывода времени
        setDisplayFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        // Диапазон данных между minimumDateTime и maximumDateTime
        // Я поставил max на 2 минуты для теста. Поменяйте на свое значение
        // QDate для обоих границ можно не менять
        setDateTimeRange(QDateTime(QDate(2000, 1, 1), QTime(0,0,0)),
                         QDateTime(QDate(2000, 1, 1), QTime(00,02,00)));
    }

    virtual void stepBy(int steps) {
        // Упрощенная реализация
        // При помощи кнопок можно изменять только секунды
        if( currentSection() != QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection )
            return;

        // Если текущая секция это секунды, то шаг 5 секунд
        steps *= 5; // Умножить, потому что при движении вниз steps отрицательный

        // Если по-простому, то при подходе к верхней границе
        if( steps > 0 && sectionText(QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection) == "55") {
            // добавляем 5 сек к текущему времени
            // тем самым перескакиваем через ограничение редактирования виджета
            QDateTime dt = dateTime().addSecs(5);
            // если полученное значение больше верхней границы, то
            // устанавливаем его чуть ниже верхней границы, чтобы
            // не блокировалось движение вниз (почему и где оно блокируется? не знаю)
            if( dt >= maximumDateTime())
                dt = maximumDateTime().addSecs(-1);
            setTime(dt.time());
        } 
        else if( steps < 0 && sectionText(QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection) == "05" ) {
            // два этих else if это два хака для перехода через нижнюю границу
            // без блокировки
            QDateTime dt = dateTime().addMSecs(-5001);
            if( dt <= minimumDateTime() )
                dt = minimumDateTime();
            setTime(dt.time());
        }
        else if( steps < 0 && sectionText(QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection) == "59" ) {
            QDateTime dt = dateTime().addMSecs(time().msec() != 0? -4999: -4000);
            if( dt <= minimumDateTime() )
                dt = minimumDateTime();
            setTime(dt.time());
        }
        else {
            QTimeEdit::stepBy(steps);
        }
    }    
};
```

Короче, сильно не тестил, но для "круглых" границ диапазона (типа таких 00:00:00, 10:10:00) должно работать

Comment: только полноценная реализация будет несколько сложнее, т.к. обычный `QTimeEdit` перематывает тот разряд, который сейчас активен...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, надо еще проверять что сейчас перематывается :) Не удивительно, что команда Qt настолько упростила принцип редактирования этого виджета. Пожалуй, я тоже упрощу немного :)